# prayer rugs or mats

Tags: halacha, tefilla, sources-mekorot, bowing-kneeling

a discussion came up regarding prostration during prayer, it was explained to me that although prostration is not always forbidden, that the use of 'prayer mats or rugs' is assur. It was also mentioned the the use of 'prayer rugs or mats' had a pagan origin associated "magical carpet" myths. Additionally, it was added that if the floor is stone material it should be covered to create a separation, but that specific 'prayer mats or rugs' of personal size and shape that resemble those of Christian and Muslim prayer mats were not.

I found this interesting but could not find any sources for this issue. Is there any sources that prohibit a particular type of mat or rug?

Comment: You were lied to. The Rambam specifically allows using a rug.  http://www.chayas.com/qidah.htm

Comment: @Aaron A link to a particular chapter in Rambam would be more convincing...

Comment: If you dont like the answer below consider further clarifying your intent.

Comment: ה  בתי כנסייות ובתי מדרשות--נוהגין בהן כבוד, מכבדין אותן, ומרבצין אותן.  ונהגו כל ישראל בספרד ובמערב בשנער וארץ הצבי, להדליק עששייות בבתי כנסייות, ולהציע בקרקען מחצלות כדי לישב עליהן.  ובערי אדום, יושבין שם על הכיסאות. hilkoth birkath kohanim 11 5

i use a rug for daily prayer

Comment: @Aryah jews muslims christians from the middle east all used the same middle eastern type rugs. only recently have muslims been using prayer rugs with designs of the kaaba on it and other things. i have never seen christian rugs. as can been seen by the sothebys websites, there are many personal jewish prayer rugs with many designs on them http://www.rugrag.com/post/Sothebys-Judaica2c-Dec-172c-2008--A-Hebrew-Silk-Kashan-Rug-Lot-128.aspx http://www.rugrag.com/post/Silk-Hebrew-Kashan-Persian-Rug-with-Inscriptions2c-Christies-Lot-682c-Sale-7616.aspx

Comment: https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/c8/da/fb/c8dafb4fc5b358f04caa3ce17d6e27fd.jpg most of these rugs come from persia as the middle eastern rugs usually come from persia

Comment: samaritans also use them: http://www.lifeintheholyland.com/images/Samaritan_Passover,_praying_standing,_mat01846.jpg
http://luirig.altervista.org/cpm/albums/matson-21/11293-The-Samaritan-Passover-on-Mt--Gerizim--Evening-prayer---Another-view-of-evening-prayer--.jpg
http://palestine.assafir.com/Medias/Photos/2013/956x643/fc57a181-7601-4ba7-b284-0d9581ffa72e.jpg

Comment: @MoriDowidhYa3aqov thanks, thats very interesting, but it actually causes me to wonder even more about minhag or halakhah sources, because with something used by Jews for prayer service it seems out of character not to have regulations defining how its made, what material it should be, appropriate size and shape, whether it should be made by a jew etc. it would surprise me if this isn't discussed somewhere. I'm happy I asked, because this turns out to be more interesting then I expected.

Comment: @Aryah why would you think there should be a specific size and shape that needs to be defined. there is no reason to define the size and shape of chairs and tables people use in the synagogue nor is there a reason to define it for a prayer rug. in regards to the material, as long as it is not stone (rug made out of stone?) it is fine. why would you think otherwise? what is the purpose of a rug? to sit on it. the minhagh is already stated in the source i gave you. in middle eastern countries people sat on rugs and in europe they sat on chairs. theres nothing more to this

Comment: from what i remember, you can gather a bunch of straw together and tie it up into a "rug" and pray on it. it is quite simple to understand that there is no burden on people to go out and find some specific material just what is locally used to create seating utensils. you dont even need a prayer rug to pray as long as you dont put your face down on a stone surface. it is also a halokho to pray with a talith on. therefore if there is a stone surface, just put the talith in front of your face and put your face on the ground

Comment: I hear what your saying, but am surprised there is no conversation never the less. It is simply because it isn't just a 'rug' but specifically a 'prayer rug', often having sacred meaning to the various religious systems that use them, and we often have customs that prevent us from accidentally engaging in a practice that could be viewed as part of a foreign religion. I mean a towel, sheet or simply a rug makes sense but a specific 'prayer rug' set apart for that purpose seems worth discussing. If it is as simple as you say, thats great but I just want clarity, and get everyones view.

Comment: @Aryah there is no sacred meaning to a rug in islam from my knowledge. i just know that their prayer rugs are 2 sided one for winter times and one for summer times. lighter colors being for summer and darker for winter. it has no religious significance only custom on how to make a rug and to change things up a bit during seasons. a talith or shamlei is used as a bed covering or a sack to carry goods in. why would there be a reason to discuss this? a talith/shamlei has no holiness to it. a prayer rug is no different than a regular rug. both are used for prayer

Comment: sometimes a prayer rug is put on top of a regular rug that is just to secure cleanliness of the area you put your face on so or it just became a habit to pray on a prayer rug instead of a regular one. literally no reason to differentiate between a rug and a prayer rug

Comment: @MoriDowidhYa3aqov I think you are correct. I am actually relieved that the person was wrong and a little embarressed I believed them...I did discover that the muslim/Christian and especially hindu prayer mats do have symbolic religious meaning and some do have specifically religious images on them, these naturally wouldn't be acceptable, but without these they are just rugs. This leads me to another question as I discovered, body position is very important and it appears we are not supposed to prostrate the same ways as others, so Ill have to ask this in another thread..lol. thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in [Do Jews Kneel in Prayer?](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1508300/jewish/Do-Jews-Kneel-in-Prayer.htm) One is allowed to kneel as long as one puts an interruption such as a towel or a rug on the floor. Please note that we normally do not prostrate ourselves except on Rosh Hashannah and Yom Kippur.

Shulchan Aruch Harav says that the basic halacha is for nefilas apaim (tachanun) after shmoneh esrai, but that we just put our heads on our hands instead of a full prostration.

> However, the Code of Jewish Law states that if you put an intervening
> substance between your knees and the stone floor, then it is permitted
> to kneel.2 Therefore, on Yom Kippur, when we do kneel and bow down
> with our faces to the floor, people bring towels to kneel on, since
> many synagogues (especially in Israel) have stone or tile floors.
>
> When it comes to daily prayers, however, we are concerned about
> transgressing this prohibition and therefore do not kneel in prayer.

[Shulchan Aruch Harav 131:1](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/3302217/jewish/Shulchan-Aruch-Chapter-131-Laws-Relating-to-Supplications-that-Follow-Shemoneh-Esreh.htm)

> In addition, any person is forbidden to prostrate himself on a
> stone<sup>11</sup> floor,<sup>4</sup> even when he does not spread out
> his hands and feet entirely. This was ordained [as a safeguard] lest
> one prostrate oneself with his hands and feet spread out, which
> contravenes a Scriptural prohibition<sup>12</sup> for which one is
> liable for lashes, as it is written,<sup>13</sup> *“Do not place a
> stone floor<sup>14</sup> in your land to prostrate yourself upon it.”*
> [Prostrating oneself on a stone floor] is permitted only in the [Beis
> Ha]Mikdash.
>
> <sup>11</sup>. The Scriptural prohibition applies only to a stone floor.
> It does not apply to a wooden floor, nor to a floor (even of stone)
> that is covered with an intervening substance such as linoleum. (See
> Rambam, Hilchos Avodas Kochavim 6:7; Rama, Yoreh Deah 131:8.)
> Therefore, while saying Aleinu in the course of the Mussaf services of
> Rosh HaShanah and Yom Kippur, when it is customary to kneel and to
> prostrate oneself until one’s forehead touches the floor, one should
> first spread a handkerchief or the like on the floor if it is made of
> stone. (See sec. 621:12 in the volume on Rosh HaShanah and Yom Kippur
> in the present Bilingual Edition; Sefer HaMinhagim: The Book of
> Chabad-Lubavitch Customs, p. 120.)

Comment: `is [sic] there any sources prohibiting the use of prayer mats or rugs?` This seems to be the primary question, and it does not appear to be addressed.

Comment: @mevaqesh The question seems to be answered as the sources I point to say that we do spread a towel or a rug for those times that we actually kneel (on Rosh Hashannah and Yom Kippur)

Comment: I see some sources that don't prohibit it, but I am failing to find those that do.

Comment: @mevaqesh Then the answer would seem to be that it is not prohibited, but not needed since it is not normally done. I have a cloth made for Yom Kippur with *Va'anachnu kor'im* written on it.

Comment: You seem to be ignoring my comments, and pretending that the question was whether something is prohibited or permitted.

Comment: the answer is useful and i am familiar with most of what is permitted but i have'nt found any sources as to any prohibitions concerning a particular type of rug or mat used specifically for prayer purposes. The concern seems to be with the origins of the christian and muslim style 'prayer mats' and their use by jews? I'm sure there are varying local customs but am just looking for sources in general to support this prohibition.

Comment: @Aryah Just to clarify, useful information that does not itself constitute an answer should be relegated to footnotes.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/27143)

Comment: @LN6595 The question was is a "prayer rug" forbidden or are there any sources that it is forbidden. My answer is that it does not appear to be forbidden and the sources say that it is required under circumstances that require prostration and not otherwise. As a result, it is an answer to the question.

Comment: @Aryah It appears from the sources that it is not forbidden.

Comment: @sabbahillel thank you for the info, since this is all there appears to be on the subject, Ill accept that as the answer, if I find anything else I'll let you know. I appreciate you.